# Bash/Awk script: newline problems

Tags: bash, awk, newline

I had to add a column on a text file (edit with Notepad++ on Windows), adding an incremental counter.

I've wrote my bash-awk script on Ubuntu and used it on the text file imported from Windows. It works fine, but the new column is on a newline and not near other columns.

Even if I pipe `sed 's/\r\n//g'` the column is on a newline.

Could this be a problem over the different handle on the newline between Unix and Windows or something is wrong with my sed instruction?

Thanks

Comment: Sed works line by line, so it doesn't remove new lines with this instruction. Try with `tr -d \\r\\n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file looks something like this:

```
col1 col2
col3
col1 col2
col3
```

Use this to append alternating lines and remove the carriage return:

```
sed 'N;s/\r\n/ /'
```

The result will look like:

```
col1 col2 col3
col1 col2 col3
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!! Could you please explain me the meaning of that `N;` ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @V4l3ri4: The `N` appends the next line to the current one. The `;` is a command separator.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\r\n//g'
```

will never delete new line even if it is presented with `\r\n` (which is not usual in the unix world). It is because `sed` reads data line by line and it simply doesn't know about newlines symbols.
There is the only way to remove newlines with `sed` is to add next line to current pattern and remove newline symbol. To apply it on the whole file you need to do it in cycle:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'
```

Also there is useful tool `tr` that is much better in removing new lines on huge files:

```
tr -d '\n'
```

Also seems you will need to convert dos newline to unix newline and may be vice versa. Use `dos2unix` or `unix2dos` perl scripts for that.

Comment: On my system `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` are symlinks to `fromdos` which is a binary.

Comment: Seems it depends on distributive or platform.

Answer (score 0):

I would pipe through `flip -u` first

Comment: If you have `flip` (I don't - never heard of it).

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this on Ubuntu, I would pass the file through unix2dos first, which might have to be installed as  `sudo apt-get install -y tfordos`. That would convert the file to \n line termination.

If your target platform is Windows, then you'll need to account for the \r\n line termination. I hope this helps.